# Bayes Net Parameter Learning in pymc

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, pymc, bayesian-network

My goal is to infer the conditional probability tables (CPT) from the classic [rain, sprinker, wet grass problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network).  Normally in this problem we know the CPTs and, given an observation like "the grass is wet" we query the bayes net for the marginal probabilities of rain or sprinkler.

Instead, I have a set of state observations of each node in the graph:

```
rain, sprinkler, wet grass
T, F, T
F, F, F
T, F, T
T, T, T
```

and so on.

I want to infer the CPTs using pymc but I'm having trouble thinking of how to express the graph in the model.  In my mind I have the following:

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np
p_rain = pm.Beta('p_rain',1,1)
rain = pm.Bernoulli('rain', p_rain)
sprinkler = [pm.Dirichlet('sprinkler%i' % i, np.ones(2)) for i in xrange(2)]
grass_wet = [pm.Dirichlet('grass_wet%i' % i, np.ones(2)) for i in xrange(4)]
```

This describes the CPTs seen [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/SimpleBayesNet.svg) for this problem.

The difficulty I'm having now is thinking about how to use the observations I have to train this model.  pymc will perform the sampling chain of drawing  from `p_rain` which provides a realization of `rain`.  This is then used to set the CPT of `sprinkler` which will return a conditional probability of sprinkler on or off and a bernoulli trial from that will return the state of the `sprinkler` which is then used, in conjunction with `rain`, to choose the conditional probability of `grass_wet`.

The steps of turning `rain` into a CPT from `sprinkler` and both of those into a CPT for `grass_wet` are missing in my code.

How does one specify that chain within two (I assume) pymc stochastic variables that will then be fed observations?

Any examples outside this of parameter learning that are applicable I'm up for.  Or any examples in other Bayes net packages would help.  I can work to translate what I see into my specific syntax/package.

Comment: Sorry, not an answer but I am also struggling with how to approach parameter learning in Bayesian networks. Did you get any insight on this that you might be willing to share?